# How to make this PHP satement shorter?

Tags: php

Make this if condition shorter.

```
if($birth_date>30&&($birth_month==2||$birth_month==4||$birth_month==6||$birth_month==9||$birth_month==11))
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Sounds more like we should do your work, which we won't

Comment: "Please", "Here what I've done", "Can you", etc.. etc..

Comment: Also, what you are looking for is a `switch()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Put the possible values of birth month in a array.

```
$birth_month_values= array(2, 4, 6, 9,11);
if($birth_date>30 && in_array($birth_month,$birth_month_values))
```

Comment: Good.  I had if ($birth_date>30 && in_array($birth_month, array(2, 4, 6, 9, 11)))